# Getting current date with javascript with HTTP Date format

Tags: javascript, http

i'm looking for a way to get the current date and time in the HTTP date format which is for example "Tue, 15 Nov 1994 08:12:31 GMT". I would like to get that with JavaScript.
I tried with:

```
new Date().toString()
```

but this gives me a different format like: "Tue Aug 20 2013 00:19:28 GMT+0200".
I would need to invert the month with the day and put a coma between the day of the week and the day of the month.
How can i get that format?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1056730/1618257

Answer (score 22):

The [HTTP date format](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1) you mention is actually an [RFC-1123 timestamp](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt). The `toUTCString` function on the `Date` object is supposed to [return a compatible value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString).

You can validate this with [this sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/ZAMN7/).

Comment: According to [RFC 7231 HTTP/1.1 §7.1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) the  "preferred format is a fixed-length and single-zone subset of the date and time specification used by the Internet Message Format [RFC5322]." That may still be compatible, but it requires some more research.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleString` method with specific parameters and some tweaks. `toLocaleString` alone can return similar string, but with two commas and without `GMT`, like `Sun, 20 Nov 2022, 12:37:06`. So we remove second comma with `replace` and add missing timezone.

```js
const dateHeader = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', {
  timeZone: 'UTC',
  hour12: false,
  weekday: 'short',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
}).replace(/(?:(\d),)/, '$1') + ' GMT';

console.log(dateHeader);
```